# Commutative Diagram of Composition and Addition (Chain Homotopies)

Tags: homological-algebra, diagram-chasing

In my Homological Algebra class we have defined and studied a lot of things through commutative diagrams. However, when we got to defining chain homotopies, we had to add a descriptive statement beyond "the diagram commutes".

Wikipedia does the same thing, saying that we require $f-g = d_B h + h d_A$ and putting up:

> [image: this diagram]

---

---

Is there a way to read off this condition directly from the diagram, or to add information to the diagram directly so that the addition and subtraction can be read off of it?

Comment: The equality of any two morphisms $\varphi$ and $\psi$ from $X$ to $Y$ is equivalent to  the diagram $X \underset{\psi}{\overset{\varphi}{\rightrightarrows}} Y$ commuting, but maybe you're looking for something different?

Comment: @NateGallup yeah I think I'm looking for something different. I want to know if there's a way to read off from the diagram that $f^n - g^n = d_B^{n-1}h^n + h^{n+1}d_A^n$ for all $n$. In particular, I don't know how one would read the addition and subtraction off of the diagram

Comment: Note that the diagram that you drew in your question actually already does not commute (e.g. $f^n \neq g^n$), so putting additional arrows won't make it commute anyway.  Addition and subtraction just add new arrows, i.e. $f^n - g^n$ and $d_B^{ n - 1} h^n + h^{n + 1} d_A^n$ are two new arrows from $A^n$ to $B^n$. My suggestion was that you have a separate diagram $A^n \underset{d_B^{ n - 1} h^n + h^{n + 1} d_A^n}{\overset{f^n - g^n}{\rightrightarrows}} B^n$ for these and require that this commutes in addition to the usual chain complex one.

Comment: @NateGallup I _think_ that's what I'm looking for, would you be able to write one and put it as an answer?